# Xamarin iOS App Size 60% Increase Since Last Build With Same Code

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.ios, xamarin.forms

I have a Xamarin Forms app that is currently on the App Store that I built and submitted in October 2016 (with what I assume was the latest versions of Xamarin Studio and Xamarin.iOS back then). The app has a size of 50 mb on the App Store.

After doing a few updates to the app, I build it now (AppStore config, then Archive) and the size is 82 mb. Confused by this balloon in size, I switched back to the git tag of the version that is currently in the App Store. I can build the **same exact tag/version/code** for that October 2016 release and it's App Store size is now 80 mb.

I am using the latest Xamarin Studio (6.3 build 863), Xamarin.iOS (10.8.0.175), etc.

Why has the size grown by 60%? No application code or libraries have changed, only newer versions of Xamarin Studio and Xamarin.iOS. How do I figure out what is going on here? I can do an Add-Hoc build on my device and see that is only taking up ~55 mb, very close to what I see from the App Store.

Also, note that  I am not comparing the .ipa size. I am comparing the "Estimated App Store Size" shown from the archive screen in Xamarin Studio after archiving a build. The same size difference is reflected after submitting the signed build via application loader to iTunes Connect and verifying from iTunes Connect > Activity > All Builds > App Store File Sizes.

**Update Sept 5th 2017**

Not sure what changed but now with the latest version of Xamarin iOS, Version: 10.12.0.20 (just updated), my app size is now back down in the 60mb range... Didn't change anything else.

Comment: could check to see if any image assets have been set to content rather than bundle resource, In some of my applications this has lead to a baloon in the application size.

Comment: @Digitalsa1nt I just verified that all assets are bundled resources (except the two iTunes artwork ones).

Answer (score 3):

> I can do an Add-Hoc build on my device and see that is only taking up ~55 mb,

You likely have some different options between your configuration, e.g.

- managed linker settings, e.g. **Don't link** versus **Link SDK**;
- targeted architectures, e.g. `armv7+arm64` versus `armv7+armv7s+arm64`;

> How do I figure out what is going on here?

Compare your build logs, in particular the options given to the `mtouch` tool. That will generally pinpoint the difference quickly.

> I am comparing the "Estimated App Store Size"

Always compare the IPA (file) size. The algorithm to guess the final size is known to be often (very) wrong. The estimation also comes from Apple's tools so they will vary with the version of Xcode you're using (which is unlikely to be identical to the one you used last fall).

Side note: the final size is even trickier to guess when bitcode is enabled (which is only for tvOS and watchOS builds right now).

Comment: Should I expect the Ah-Hoc build installed on my device to be the same size as if I downloaded it from the App Store if all build settings are the same? The `ipa` size here is only about 20mb, but my understanding is that is much larger once signed by apple for AppStore distribution.

Comment: If you want to measure an app's size, here is the documentation, which files to take into consideration: https://developer.apple.com/library/content/qa/qa1795/_index.html I would *NOT* just take a look at the .ipa file, but rather take a look at the thinned app bundle in your case.

Comment: _If you want to measure an app's size,_ -> yes, even if it's quite often wrong. However the question is about **comparing app size from today with something done months earlier** and that's better compared with the IPA file size.

Comment: @kspearrin forget app store size, you'll not get accurate comparison using this data (unless you submit your new version and download it). App are encrypted and compressed, but encrypted data does not compress well. Since not every file needs encryption it makes it hard to guess the final size (without doing the exact same process).

Comment: Another interesting finding here is that when viewing the app on iTunes Connect > All Builds, comparing Oct. version with my latest version I see Oct. build compressed 40mb, App Store size 50mb vs. Today build compressed 20mb, App Store Size 80mb. Wild... Let me try to dig into the ipa contents more to see if I can find any big differences.

Comment: Unfortunately I do not have the old Oct ipa anymore to compare to. Is there some way I can download it from iTunes connect or something?

Comment: @Lepidopteron Following the advise from https://developer.apple.com/library/content/qa/qa1795/_index.html , I can see this when unzipping the ipa: https://pastebin.com/2vJSzXNh

Something to note from there is that my App Extension Size seems very large compared to the main app and Mono and also that all dependency libs for the extension seem to be duplicated.

Comment: After unloading the app extension project from my solution and building with AppStore > Archive, the size has now gone back down to "Estimated App Store Size: 28mb" (from 80mb previously). Wow....

Could there be some regression involved with app extensions in newer versions of Xamarin here?

Comment: @kspearrin check you build settings, both for the app and the extension - if the later is much bigger then it's likely build changes in that project. You might also want to try the XI 10.10 (beta right now) which introduce code sharing between apps and extensions (to reduce the app size).

Comment: @poupou I am having a hard time seeing a problem with the build settings. Both are set to ARM64 and Link All (with the same skips). Screenshots: http://imgur.com/a/PFfGM . Also, if you care to have a look, the source can be found here (Oct build is the v1.0.0 tag): https://github.com/bitwarden/mobile . I will check out XI 10.10

Comment: @poupou Installed XI 10.10 from the beta channel and am not seeing any code sharing improvements in the generated ipa. See https://pastebin.com/1ZxrAqVe . Same app size as well. Is there some setting for this I have to enable in the config?

Comment: It's automatic but there are some conditions to meet (e.g. min iOS 8 to support frameworks). If sharing cannot be done you'll see warnings that tell you why.

Comment: Hmm, did you post this on the Xamarin forum? The core developers Will likely know more

Comment: @poupou Not sure what changed but now with the latest version of Xamarin iOS, Version: 10.12.0.20 (just updated), my app size is now back down in the 60mb range... Didn't change anything else.

Answer (score 1):

My guess is that xamarin is packing a lot of unneeded stuff, maybe old images or similar that you are no longer using. I have experienced that myself.

Go to you project folder and delete everything in the obj folder

```
<myproject>/iOS/obj/
```

Usually you will see two folders in there: iPhone and iPhoneSimulator.

Delete those and build everything again, there's a good chance that will solve it

Comment: Although this has been the case in the past, this doesn't solve the problem I am currently having.

Answer (score 0):

Are you using the same version of Xamarin to build your code. I am willing to bet that is the issue. Something changed in how Xamarin builds apps since the last time you released it and is blowing up your app build size.

If you actually have the same code you released back then do you know what version of Xamarin you used back then? Honestly since the only thing that's changed is the Xamarin compiler it is most definitely the issue.

Comment: The mentioned Xamarin and Xamarin.iOS version were not available back in Oct 2016: Xamarin Studio (6.3 build 863), Xamarin.iOS (10.8.0.175), so this has changed

Comment: I am assuming no since I am using the latest for today to build now. But how do I figure out what is causing it from the version change?

Comment: Gotta dig into the patch notes and see if it blew up any implementations you're currently using.

Answer (score 0):

There are four things to do:

DELETE bin and obj folder from client project

CHANGE architecture to only support 64

CONFIGURE the linker.
Best is to try and build your app with linker active, but the more nuget packages you use, the less likely this is

and most importantly:
Set your build config to RELEASE and not DEBUG
(if you forget that, stores will accept your app but size can easily be doubled or even trippled)

This is how the minimal setup should look like:
[image]

Then dont forget that XAMARIN adds libraries like crazy to your app. I once read that the smallest app with NO content at all is at least 7 MB. This only gets larger with each package and each new dependency.